# What kind of weather to expect in Budapest in late March/early April?

Tags: weather-and-climate, clothing, budapest

I'll be traveling for 5 days in late March to Budapest; and am wondering what kind of weather to expect.

I usually check for weather at weather underground as they provide future weather "forecasts" based on historical data; but for March the prediction is anywhere from a [high of 20 to a low of -2<sup>o</sup>C; and average of 14 to 1C](http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/LHBP/2016/3/10/MonthlyCalendar.html?req_city=Budapest&req_state=&req_statename=Hungary&reqdb.zip=00000&reqdb.magic=6&reqdb.wmo=12838).

So is this an overcoat/parka weather, or more of a light sweater and jacket weather?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Late March can be pretty cool in Budapest, I mean less chance for 20 degrees (Celsius) and more for 10! Prepare for possible rain and wind also. Nights will be between 0 and 5 degrees, so take a warm sweater and a waterproof jacket with you. Enjoy Budapest anyway!